# Are VSTS upgrades applied to inherited processes?

Tags: azure-devops

We want to add/change states and reasons for our work items in VSTS.  I believe that I will need to inherit a process first and make changes to the inherited process.  Are future upgrades to VSTS applied to inherited processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to custom work item fields in an inherited process. And you can refer the document [Add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-field?view=vsts).

After updating the inherited process template, the projects which use the inherited process will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thank you!  I did not word my question correctly.  Are upgrades in releases of VSTS applied automatically to inherited process templates?  In other words, are enhancements to "out-of-the-box" process templates going to be automatically applied to inherited process templates?

Comment: Do you mean "out-of-the-box" process templates are Agile, Scrum and CMMI process templates? What do you want to do in a VSTS release?

Comment: Yes.  If enhancements are added to the Agile, Scrum and CMMI process templates, will they also be added to the inherited process templates?

Comment: Yes, the inherited process templates will be updated automatically.

Comment: Great!  Thank you!!